# What is empirical mean of centripetal acceleration

Tags: acceleration, kinematics

We have this formula for centripetal acceleration - 
$a = v \frac{d\theta}{dt} = v\omega = \frac{v^2}{r}$

but in case of *usual* acceleration i know that speed in $t_1 = v_0 + a \cdot (t_1 - t_0)$

but in circular case i don't understande the nature of acceleration, speed is always the same if motion is uniform, but acceleration is not zero.

EDIT:
Suppose T is 1. $t_0 = 0, t_1 = .25$, so $v$ was rotated for $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So $\frac{\bar{a}}{4} = \bar{v_1} - \bar{v_0}$ and $|a| = 4\sqrt{v^2 + v^2} = 4\sqrt{2} v$, but with previous formula magnitude of a is $\frac{v^2}{4r}$
.

ANSWER:
physical meaning of $a$ is the length of an arc swept out by velocity vector!

Comment: Suppose you have a point moving along a circle. The point's distance from the center never changes, yet it's velocity is non-zero. What gives?

Comment: The magnitude of $\vec{v}$ is constant, but not it's direction.

Comment: There is much wrong with your question - namely the units don't work out for most of your equations except for the very first one.  It's hard then to decipher what exactly you're asking.  Jinawee makes a good point that you should keep in mind: Acceleration is defined by the $\frac{d \vec{v}}{dt}$ and since $\vec{v}$ is a vector, then if the direction of $\vec{v}$ changes in time (even with it's magnitude constant) then there is a non-zero acceleration.

Comment: mcFreid, vector - vector is vector, magnitudes have no units at all.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38291/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91797/

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "vector is vector."  Magnitudes can have units.  For example, the magnitude of the velocity is the speed and it has units of $\frac{m}{s}$.

Comment: The analysis in your edit is flawed in a couple of ways. (1) $T$ is not independent, but is a function of $v$ and $r$ so you should get $\bar{a} = (\sqrt{2} v)/(0.25 \cdot 2 \pi r / v) = (2\sqrt{2} v^2) / (\pi r)$. (2) The result depends on how much of a rotation you use, doing the same thing for a half rotation yields $\bar{a} = (2 v) / (0.5 \cdot 2 \pi r / v) = (2 v^2)/(\pi r)$ which is not the same as for a quarter rotation demonstrating that the analysis is not correct (I suspect tat you can repair it by taking the infinitesimal limit).

Comment: You wrote: $|a| = 4\sqrt{v^2 + v^2} = 4\sqrt{2} v$, it should be $|\vec{a}| = 4\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2} = 4v$. Anyway, $\frac{\bar{a}}{4} = \bar{v_1} - \bar{v_0}$ is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physical meaning of $a$ is the length of an arc swept out by velocity vector.